# automatically get value in JTextfield1 into JTextfield2 without press enter in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program in NETBEANS IDE where i can input a value into a JTextField1 & JTextField2, and the SUM will automatically appear into JTextField3 without having to press Enter.
When changing the value of JTextField1 or JTextField2 it will update realtime into JTextField3.

Comment: what have you done thus far?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you plan to respond to every key press, then get the underlying Document from the JTextField using getDocument(). Then add a DocumentListener to it. Your document listener will be notified when the document changes.

I suggest you look into these resources:

[JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

[How to write a DoucmentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: Plus this resources: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/ListeningtoJTextFieldEventswithaDocumentListener.htm

Comment: Though the `DocumentListener` also captures changes initiated by for example a mouse event (like Paste from a context menu).

Answer (score 2):

If I interpreted your question correctly, it should be just as easy as:

```
private JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            jTextField3.setText(jTextField1.getText());
    }
    @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
});
```

For each textfield that needs to be realtime ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably add a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29) to JTextField1 and update the text of JTextField2 accordingly. (Although you might need a [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseMotionListener%28java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener%29) too to handle drags too.)